# How to generate a dynamic mysql query in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like the users to choose which fields they want to see and which ones they don't.This is my API URI which is a get request.

```
/api/v1/admin/users/1?fields=email,id
```

This is my code  :

```
if (isset($request->fields)) {
            $temp = null;
            $items = explode(',', $request->fields);
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $temp = $temp . "'" . $item . "',";
            }
            $fields = trim($temp, ',');

            $query = User::query();
            $query->select($resourceOptions['fields']);
            $query->get();
        }
```

but I got this error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''email','id'' in 'field list' (SQL: select `'email','id'` from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null)"
```

Any help (or if someone can point me towards a good tutorial) would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laravel you can add query with `where()` clause. But in your case. It's not required.

Just run this.

```
if (isset($request->fields)) {
        $users = User::select(DB::raw($request->fields))->get();
        dd($users);
}
```

Comment: @Maryam let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tested and it is not true

Comment: @Maryam Try now.

Comment: i think he is passing request wrong way. `'email','id'` look at this.

Answer (score 0):

import

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

and

```
if (isset($request->fields)) {
    $query = User::select(DB::raw($request->fields))->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does `$resourceOptions['fields']` comes from?

You can use the array of items in the `select` function, like this:

```
if (isset($request->fields)) {
    $items = explode(',', $request->fields);
    $query = User::query();
    $query->select($items);
    $query->get();
}
```

Or like this

```
if (isset($request->fields)) {
    $query = User::query()->select(explode(',', $request->fields))->get();
}
```